# Angular unit tests with Karma/Jasmine - browser not defined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Whenever I run a unit test I get the error:

```
browser is not defined.
```

My config file is below - can anyone suggest the issue

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: './',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'www-dev/js/ionic.bundle.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'www-dev/js/app.js',
        'www-dev/js/templates.js',
        'www-dev/css/*.css',
        {pattern: 'tests/unit/unit.js', nocache: true, watched: true}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor

    preprocessors: {
        './www-dev/js/app.js': ['coverage']
    },



    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter

    reporters: ['progress','coverage'],
    coverageReporter: {
        type : 'html',
        dir : './tests/unit/'
    },

    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'IE'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually open a browser instance, Karma needs a browser launcher, which comes in the form of a plugin.

From [Karma's browser docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/browsers.html):

> Note: Most of the browser launchers need to be loaded as plugins.

Have you installed the correct launcher plugins?

- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher
- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher
- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ie-launcher